# Apache uses more memory than PHP's memory_limit

Tags: apache-2.2, php, memory, httpd

I am having some issues on a server where multiple Apache processes are being spawned and eating up the physical memory and swap.

Each `httpd` process consumes around 130MB of RES. However, PHP's `memory_limit` is set at 32MB.

The initial thinking is that there is a memory leak in PHP code - however, I don't see any particular code that could be causing this... granted the codebase is not necessarily *efficient*, however, what other explanations are there for such large memory consumption by Apache given memory_limit is set quite low?

Comment: Because apache does other things then just running php?  What other modules do you have running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memory_limit` is the maximum memory that apache is allowed to allocate per **script**. If you have multiple scripts running, on the same instance, it's normal that `httpd` uses more than 32MB.

Comment: +1 you need to tune Apache's settings: MaxClients, KeepAlive, etc. Search the web for "Apache performance tuning".